# Proof: $f(n) = n^2 - 13n \in \theta (n^2) $

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I need help with the following proof:

Prove that $f(n) = n^2 - 13n \in \theta (n^2) $

Of course, I know the definition of $\theta$, so I need to find $c'$ and $c''$ such that

$c' n^2 \le n^2 - 13n \le c'' n^2$

The right side is trivial, since $c'' = 1$ implies $n^2 - 13n \le n^2$, which is obviously correct

However, I struggle to prove the left side.

If I choose for example $c' = 0.5$, then $0.5n^2 \le n^2 - 13n$ for all $n \ge 100$ (for example)

Also $n^2 - 13n = n (n - 13)$

But I do not know how to prove the left site completely formal?!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $n>26$, then $2n-26>n$, so $n-13>\frac n2$ and $n^2-13n>n\cdot\frac n2=\frac 12n^2$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the $\Theta$ notation only matters for large $n$. Thus you only need to find constants $c'$, $c''$, and $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$,
$$ c'n^2 \leq f(n) \leq c''n^2 .$$
You have the liberty to choose $n_0$ to make your inequalities work.

Also, use `\geq` for $\geq$ not $>=$.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much already almost did prove it formally.  Were you just wondering how to formally phrase everything?

What you want to show is this:

> There exist $c' > 0$, $c'' > 0$, and $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$, we have $$c' \cdot n^2 \le n^2 - 13n \le c'' \cdot n^2$$

You found valid constants to use:  $c' = 0.5$ and $c'' = 1$.  But what about $N$?  Note that $N$ must be something that works for both $c'$ **and** $c''$.  Well, you already know that $c'' = 1$ works for all $n > 0$.  And you saw that $c' = 0.5$ works for all $n > 100$.  Therefore one possible choice for $N$ is ...

Can you take it from here?